# Function call in ng-disabled expression - allowed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-disabled` to make the submit button of a form unclickable unless all the form validations are good.

I have it working just fine when I use

```
<button ng-disabled="form.$invalid">OK</button>
```

However, there's another check I want it to complete, and this is in a controller function `foo()` (which is published on $scope in the controller's definition). I've confirmed that foo returns what I want, but when I have

```
<button ng-disabled="form.$invalid && foo()">OK</button>
```

the button never gets disabled. What am I doing wrong? Are function calls not allowed here?

Comment: does foo return true when you want it to be disabled?  Is it possible you should be using the || operator instead?

Comment: @NSjonas You're a champ, and I'm dumb sometimes. What I really wanted was `ng-disabled="form.$invalied || foo()"` (I actually had `&& !foo()` because I botched the logic in my head pretty badly).

Comment: @asfallows glad i could help.  I submitted an answer so you can resolve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I'm getting strange results, the first thing I do is ensure that any conditional logic is correct.  A very common one is to mix-up **&&** and **||**.

If you're not seeing errors in the console then the function is probably getting called and the problem is a bug in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is truly in a controller function, then you need to either expose your controller via `controllerAs` and call it via the exposed method (i.e. `controllerAs: 'ctrl'` in your route and `ctrl.foo()` in your template instead), or you need to instead publish this method on `$scope`.

Comment: foo is published on $scope. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue, kinda lost the logic in my head, kept thinking I should be using `&&` but in reality the logic should have been `||`,
e.g.

```
ng-disabled="!privilegeReviews.length || checkSaveRevertValidity()
```